# How closure and constructor work from the perspective of js engine

Tags: javascript, constructor, closures

All:

I am pretty new to JS, could anyone give me a little detail how JS engine create closure and how does it run constructor function? Maybe from the perspective how memory(data structure like stack) allocated and how reference assigned

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing Closures in a Compiler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18051012/implementing-closures-in-a-compiler)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how common JS engines do it exactly, but the general process is as followed:

- Variables belong to a frame. A frame captures its outer frame.
- A closure captures the frame it belongs to.
- It captures a frame instead of the variable directly, so it can change value of a variable in an outer frame and the change will be visible in the outer frame. Smallest example

  ```
  var x = 1;
  (function () { x = 2 })();  // <- a closure that gets invoked directly.
  console.log(x);  // x == 2
  ```
- Closures, also called function-objects, are normal variables and normal garbage collection applies. (This is really far from trivial, because a function "knows itself", c.f. ["letrec"](https://www.google.de/#q=letrec&gws_rd=cr).)
- In fact there is no difference between functions and closures assigned to a variable in JS, c.f. ["hoisting"](https://www.google.de/#q=stackoverflow+javascript+variable+hoisting).

So, if you would want to implement a JavaScript engine, a frame would be just a structure in C:

```
var a, b, c;
```

->

```
struct frame_42_t {
    void *parent_frame;
    object *a, *b, *c;
};
```

Of course the actual engines do a lot of optimizations, e.g. lifetime deduction of a variable. A temporary variable would not be stored in a frame if the engine can deduct that it won't be read again:

```
var temp = a;
a = b;
c = temp;
```

A closure is then just another struct:

```
struct function_4711_t {
    void *parent_frame;
    result_type (*call)(void *frame);
};

...

function_4711->call(function_4711->parent_frame);
```

Another obvious optimization is that the engine tries to deduce the types of the variables, but I guess that's about it when you only want to understand the basics.